# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() Instagram API

Tags: php, api, instagram

I'm using [this sample code](http://www.mauriciocuenca.com/blog/2011/02/instagram-api-implementation-in-php/#comment-11782) to call my person Instagram feed. Everything works the second time, but on the initial call I get a `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`. Can't figure out why it only works part of the time...

The PHP code:

```
<?php
    foreach ($response['data'] as $data) {
        $link = $data['link'];
        $id = $data['id'];
        $caption = $data['caption']['text'];
        $author = $data['caption']['from']['username'];
        $thumbnail = $data['images']['low_resolution']['url'];
        $username = $data['user']['username'];
        $fullname = $data['user']['full_name'];
?>
```

Comment: `var_dump($response);`

Comment: There seems to be sth. woring with $response['data']

Comment: @zerkms could you elaborate please?

Comment: @Bad Dog: what actually? Have you read documentation for `foreach` and `var_dump`? Have you checked the `var_dump` output? Have you read the error message text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes for some reasons api may not return response as you expected. So you must validate data before using it.

```
if(isset($response['data']) && is_array($response['data'])){
    //your code here...
}
```